# Big loss of Image quality when decode from InputStream

Tags: android, imageview, android-bitmap

I'm trying to retrieve an image from a URL and show it on an ImageView. The task seems quite easy and i can show the images in the ImageView but the quality is really bad.

Here's what I did so far:

```
 Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
 options.inScaled = false;
 options.inDither = false;
 options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
 InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
 mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in,null,options);
```

The ImageView properties:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        .../>
```

I also tried to directly use the `decodeStream` Without Options but the result is still the same.

Comment: What is the size of ImageView in pixels and the image downloaded size in pixels?

Comment: @Niko the ImageView properties are shown in my post. width = match_parent and the height is set with ratio with `androi:weight`. Concerning the downloaded image the size change from one picture to another but I expect that the ImageView will scale the picture automatically

Comment: But how much are they in pixels? If the downloaded image pixel size is greatly lower than the ImageView pixels size, the quality cannot be good.

Comment: You are right the pixel size of the downloaded pictures is lower than the ImageView. Then is it better to change the properties of the ImageView on runtime depending on the size of the downloaded pictures ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is okay, you could also consider using dithering for better result. If the images you download are greatly smaller in pixels than the `ImageView` the result looks bad.

Solution is to have better quality images to download or change the `ImageView` to be smaller. You could adjust the `ImageView` width and height programmatically after you have decoded the `Bitmap`. If the `Bitmap` pixel size is lower than the `ImageView`, make the `ImageView` smaller.

Comment: So it's better to set `inDither` to true ? I mean in general for better quality

Comment: I recommend reading this to give the idea how dithering can affect an image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither